# Why codeigniter google maps library doesn't load marker icon

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I use codeigniter with included Google maps API V3 library. Everything is loaded in constructor etc...

My controller contents from...

```
   $config['icon'] = "http://localhost/xampp/zadanie_/myimg.png";
   $config['center'] = $data['lat'].",".$data['lon'];
   $config['map_height'] = 180;
   $config['sensor'] = false;
   $config['map_width'] = 198;
   $config['disableMapTypeControl'] = TRUE;
   $config['disableStreetViewControl'] = TRUE;
   $config['zoom'] = '10';

   $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

   $marker = array();
   $marker['position'] = $data['lat'].",".$data['lon'];
   $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
```

after, loading page...
generated Javascript contains these piece of code:

```
function initialize() {

                 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.1405,17.0948);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false}
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.1405,17.0948);

            var markerOptions = {
                map: map,
                position: myLatlng      
            };
            marker_0 = createMarker(markerOptions);


            }
```

There is no **icon** item. What am I doing bad? :(

Comment: Thanks for using my library. I'll soon be looking at locking down the validation so mistakes like this are brought to the users attention right away. Feel free to give me a shout direct if you run into any other problems. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Replacing  `$config['icon'];` with `$marker['icon'];` solves the problem.